# Function not returning true when it should

Tags: javascript

I am learning how to program, and I received the following task in my coding class:

> Make a function which take a parameter and returns true if no numbers are negative

I've tried to do this using the below code:

```
function allPositive(a) {
    if(a > 0) {
        return true
    }
}
```

I tried to run `allPositive([4,3,2,1])`, but it didn't return  `true`. How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you calling it? How are you testing the return value? Why **all** positive when you are only dealing with a single number?

Comment: If I copy that function into my browser console and then run `allPositive(1)` it returns `true`.  When I call `allPositive(-1)` it returns `undefined`.   What's the problem?

Comment: You need to return `false` outside of the `if` if you want it to be something other than `undefined`.

Comment: What I'm wondering...is the variable "a" an array? If so, then you'd need to iterate over the array and check each value.

Comment: Yes, a is an Array. I tried to type in allPositive([4,3,2,1]) in hopes of getting back true, but then nothing will happen.

I am sorry if my english/description was bad as English is my third language

Comment: @JonWillyLarsen Aha. Yeah, having an array be the parameter was the key part of the question. I've edited your question to include that in and nominated the question for re-opening (now that you've given a reproducable example). Check the last paragraph in Eric's answer for a brief introduction to using a for-loop. Congratulations on three languages, by the way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting to return the case when it's not positive (ie. negative). Try this way instead:

```
function allPositive(a){
    if (a > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This expression can be written in a more elegant manner as below:

```
function allPositive(a){
    return a > 0;
}
```

I would argue though, that `0` is a positive integer, thus, the comparision should be using `>=` instead.

Coming back to the original question, the task hints that there are several numbers to check, that is, an *array* of numbers. You should look up [loops](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) to iterative over all elements in an array, and check if they are all positive or negative.

The naive algorithm would be to check each element, and as soon as any is negative, return false. If you reach outside the loop, that means all are positive, then return true. Let's see what you can come up with! :)